# Compile error while returning chunked response from play 2.8.18

Tags: scala, playframework, akka-stream

I am trying out chunked response in play framework.
The below controller code works fine.

```
def chunkedSample = Action {
  val source = Source.apply(List("Hello","Hai"))
  Ok.chunked(source)
}
```

But when I change the List object to a case class as below

```
def chunkedSample = Action {
  val source = Source.apply(List(Dummy("hello")))
  Ok.chunked(source)
}
```

Where I define dummy case class as below

```
case class Dummy(hello:String)
```

I get below compilation error
`No implicit found for parameter writable:Writable[Dummy]`
I tried putting json format & writes in companion object below but didn't work.

```
object Dummy{
  implicit val write = Json.writes[Dummy]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error tells you that you are missing writes, so you need to add them. There are different ways to add them, but for case class I find next example as most convenient. It also has read as you will most probably need it in the future.

```
case class Dummy(hello: String)

implicit lazy val dummyReads: Reads[Dummy] = (
  (__ \ "hello").read[String]
)(Dummy)

implicit lazy val dummyWrites: Writes[Dummy] = (
  (__ \ "hello").write[String]
)(unlift(Dummy.unapply))
```

More documentation could be found on [this](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ScalaJsonCombinators) page of Play framework official docs.